# Are there any differences between Python2 PriorityQueue and Python3 PriorityQueue's put method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm solving leetcode's [Merge K Sorted Lists problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists).

The same algorithm that uses a `PriorityQueue` from Python2's `Queue` module throws an error for the `PriorityQueue` in Python3's `queue` module.

Python2 version:

```py
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None


from Queue import PriorityQueue

class Solution(object):
    def mergeKLists(self, lists):
        """
        :type lists: List[ListNode]
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        # Load the first node from every linked list into a priority queue
        prQueue = PriorityQueue()
        for node in lists:
            if node:
                prQueue.put((node.val, node))

        head = ListNode(0)
        curr = head
        while not prQueue.empty():
            val, node = prQueue.get()
            curr.next = node
            curr = curr.next
            if node.next:
                prQueue.put((node.next.val, node.next))

        return head.next
```

The above code works fine.

Python3 version:

```py
from typing import List
from queue import PriorityQueue

class Solution:
    def mergeKLists(self, lists: List[ListNode]) -> ListNode:
        # Load the first node from every linked list into a priority queue
        prQueue = PriorityQueue()
        for node in lists:
            if node:
                prQueue.put((node.val, node))

        head = ListNode(0)
        curr = head
        while not prQueue.empty():
            val, node = prQueue.get()
            curr.next = node
            curr = curr.next
            if node.next:
                prQueue.put((node.next.val, node.next))

        return head.next
```

The above code (Python3 version) does not work and outputs the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'ListNode' and 'ListNode'
    heappush(self.queue, item)
Line 227 in _put (/usr/lib/python3.6/queue.py)
    self._put(item)
Line 143 in put (/usr/lib/python3.6/queue.py)
Line 24 in mergeKLists (Solution.py)
Line 58 in _driver (Solution.py)
Line 71 in &lt;module&gt; (Solution.py)
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `ListNode` not implementing the `__lt__` method.

This is the change in python3 that affects you.. In python2 this wont be a problem as the inbuilt cmp function will be used to sort.

When you push to a PriorityQueue, it is sorted and to do that you need to have `__lt__` method implemented.

Comment: I'm passing a `tuple` to the `PriorityQueue` with its first value being a normal integer, with is the key to the `PriorityQueue` for comparison.